# Call "method" in C OOP

Tags: c, oop

I want print the information of the object I created in two ways.

The  first way which has nothing to do OOP is calling the `print` function .  the second way is similar to the approach in Python. I use `joe->print();`, it says`error: too few arguments to function ‘joe->print’`. How to do with it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct PERSON{
    char *name;
    int  age;
    int  height;
    int  weight;
    void (*print)(struct PERSON *self);
    void (*destroy)(struct PERSON *self);

} ;


typedef struct PERSON person;

void person_print(person* who)
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", who->name);
    printf("Age: %d\n", who->age);
    printf("Height: %d\n", who->height);
    printf("Weight: %d\n", who->weight);
}

person *person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    person *who = malloc(sizeof(person));
    assert(who != NULL);
    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight=weight;
    who->print=&person_print;
    return who;
    }

void person_destroy(person *who)
{
    assert(who != NULL);

    free(who->name);
    free(who);
    }

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    person *joe = person_create("Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);
    person_print(joe);
    //joe->print();

}
```

There is another problem get me confused, when we destroy the object using function`void person_destroy` , how to understand the statement `free(who->name) and free(who)`, why that Adding `free(who->age)` will cause error promotion. if I free the space storing the attributes of the struct, would `free(who)` still be necessary?

Comment: With C, you have to pass your "object"  *explicitly* as the first parameter of the method, there's no automatism for OOP. And you only need to make it a member as function pointer when you want to implement *virtual* methods. For normal methods, you just use normal fuctions (typically named `<class>_<method>()`)

Comment: `joe->print();`. Declaration is  `void (*print)(struct PERSON *self);`. Type is `void (*)(struct PERSON*)`. It expects a pointer to `struct PERSON`. Where you are passing it? Change the call to `joe->print(joe);`.

Comment: By the way, calling the `print` function directly is still OOP if you want to consider it so. It's just the equivalent of a non-virtual method, while the `joe->print` would be equivalent to a virtual method. If you have many such methods, you might want to create a const function table and just have a pointer to it in your object. That also makes sure you cannot get them mixed up.

Comment: @spectras which is typically called *vtable*, OOP languages do these things automatically

Comment: @FelixPalmen> exactly :) I assume the OP is getting an introduction to OOP. I wanted to push the concept of function pointers a bit further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1:**

Your error in using `print` without necessary argument was already explained in the comments.

You must be aware that there is no OO stuff in C. No magically appearing invisible `this` pointer...

If you want to use such a thing, you pass it! End of story. ;)

**Part 2:**

I suggest that you grab a beginner's C book and check the chapters about dynamic memory usage.

> There is another problem get me confused, when we destroy the object
>   using functionvoid person_destroy , how to understand the statement
>   free(who->name) and free(who), why that

Very easy rule:
Each block of memory that was allocated, must be free'd again.

```
person *who = malloc(sizeof(person));  // Memory block #1
...
who->name = strdup(name);              // Memory block #2
```

The secod allocates memory for a copy of the string and assigns the address to `who->name`.

> Adding free(who->age) will cause error promotion.

As `who->age` is not a pointer but an integer, of course you get an error when you use it as argument for calling `free`.
The error message probably tells you about that type mismatch.

> if I free the space storing the attributes of
>   the struct, would free(who) still be necessary?

Sure. How should `free` know anything about the innerts of the memory block it is passed?
There is no such thing as an automatically called destructor in C.